# What happens if the minSdkVersion is higher than the targetSdkVersion

Tags: android, android-manifest

The app that I am creating will only work on an specific hardware that has Android 18 in it. However, when I enable `android:targetSdkVersion > "15"` I have some issues with pressing Enter and not receiving a callback in `OnEditorActionListener.onEditorAction`.
Therefore the configuration that I have now is `android:targetSdkVersion="15" android:minSdkVersion="18"`

Will this cause any issue?

Comment: I'd be very surprised if your project even compiles with that configuration.

Comment: It actually compiles.

Comment: It probably defaults to target >= min.

Comment: @Daniel, It does not because when setting target > 15 I have an issue with onEditorAction that's avoided when target = 15.

Comment: @HéctorJúdezSapena You should probably try to fix the issue instead of trying to do this iffy thingy. Why not just ask us about the real issue?

Comment: I cannot fix the issue for next release, I am stuck with what I have. This solves the problem right now so I just wanted to ask you guys if you see anything weird on setting this configuration.

Comment: @HéctorJúdezSapena Sure, it is weird all right.